# Unique solution of AX=b

Tags: matrix-equations

If A is an (n x n)-matrix, under which conditions does the linear system Ax = b have a unique solution?
1-The matrix A is regular.
2-All entries of A are non-zero.
3-The inverse of A exists.
4-rank(A) = n
5-cond(A) = 5
6-A admits a LU-decomposition
7-det(A) = 0
8-A is upper triangular with non-zero diagonal entries.
9-cond(A) = 0

So, I think the solution would be for sure 3 and 4 and not 7.

Comment: 1 and 8 are also sufficient conditions (actually, 1, 3 and 4 are equivalent).

Comment: Yes, you are right 1 is also right!

Comment: What about cond(A) what would it be in this situation?

Comment: No idea: I don't know what it's about.

Answer (score 1):

You are right and also $1$ by [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NonsingularMatrix.html) and $8$ are true indeed for a [triangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Special_properties) the determinant is equal to the product of the diagonal entries.